# JavaScript code for many files put into one file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have several forms in different html files as in `signup.html`, `login.html`, `upload.html` and my jQuery to process these forms is in different files as in `signup.js`, `login.js`, `upload.js`. How can I better organize all this jQuery code into one file?

Comment: Is there any problem simply concatenating the scripts into one file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple like creating a namespace and then putting your methods from signup.js, login.js and upload.js into it. This will allow you to put everything in one file.

Example:

```
var FormProcessor = {};
FormProcessor.prototype.signup_form_process = function() {
};
FormProcessor.prototype.login_form_process = function() {
};
FormProcessor.prototype.upload_form_process = function() {
};
```

Then within your html files, just include the one js file and call your code like FormProcessor.signup_form_process(), etc...